# Как добавить текст в заголовок title, кликом по кнопке?

Tags: javascript

Заголовок страницы

```
<title>трек-название</title>
```

Кнопка

```
<a data-title="\f0dc трек-название" href="">play</a>
```

Нужно при нажатии на кнопку добавить текст или иконку ( \f0dc ) к титлу страницы вот сюда.

```
<title>\f0dc - трек-название</title>
```

При повторном нажатии удалить иконку.

Comment: Взгляните на мой ответ. Это в случае, если используете jQuery. Если же пользуетесь Angularjs, то скажите, я напишу решение на angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите так

```
<ul id="playlist">
    <li class="play" data-title="David Guetta - Hey Mama ft. Nicki Minaj">David Guetta - Hey Mama ft. Nicki Minaj</li>
    <li class="play" data-title="Maroon 5 - Sugar">Maroon 5 - Sugar</li>
    <li class="play" data-title="Wiz Khalifa - See You Again ft. Charlie Puth">Wiz Khalifa - See You Again ft. Charlie Puth</li>
</ul>
```

---

```
$('#playlist a').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    var title = $(this).attr('data-title')
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        document.title = "\f0dc "+title;
    } else {
        document.title = title;
    }
});
```

Comment: текст не добавляется а заменяется и повторное нажатие(удаление) тоже не работает. А через JS вообще не работает.

Comment: Код работает хорошо, но трек-название в js не вставить, можно как нибудь через ссылку, примерно так <a data-title="трек-название">

Answer (score 1):

изменение title документа

```
$('title').text('ня');
```

или

```
document.title = "ня";
```

Answer (score 0):

Если пользуетесь jQuery, то примерно так :

**HTML**

```
<a data-track="Название трека" id="play" href="">Включить трек</a>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on('click', '#play', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var this = $(this);
    var trackName = this.attr('data-track');
    // либо так var trackName = this.data('track');

    this.toggleClass('playing');
    if (this.hasClass('playing')) {
        document.title = "\f0dc - "+trackName;
    } else {
        document.title = trackName;
    }
});
```

Comment: Использую jQuery, но с этим кодом вообще перестают работать все скрипты, конфликт какой-то. И я не могу вставлять трек-название в js, а только в ссылку.

Comment: Попробуйте еще раз проверить, опечатка была.

Comment: Нужно как-то через ссылку трек-название передавать. Как нибудь так <a data-title="трек-название"> и в js что-то написать. После исправления опечатки все равно конфликт.

Comment: Обновил ответ, взгляните.

Comment: Что-то с этой строкой     var this = $(this),
        trackName = this.attr('data-title');  когда удаляю,конфликта нет

Comment: странно.. обновил, попробуйте. Одно из двух должно заработать)

Comment: Оба варианта не работают. У KYRAN вариант рабочий, только надо через data-title переделать

Comment: Попробуйте убрать `e.preventDefault();` из начала функции и добавьте `return false;` в конце функции. Попробуйте без этих двух строки вообще, переберите разные варианты, код рабочий. Удачи)

Comment: Да что с этой датой не так-то, все варианты перепробовал, может посмотрите ещё варианты? `var this = $(this);
    var trackName = this.attr('data-track');` ведь нет ошибок, а не работает с этими строками.